# Globally, blindness and visual impairment are major health problem

Tags: grammar

Here, should I write 'is' instead of 'are' in auxiliary verb?
can i use 'a major health problem'
Or Just ' major public health problem or problems

Please help me

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether you regard "blindness and visual impairment" as one problem or two.

As your statement stands, it is not quite correct -- it should either say "a major health problem" or "major health problems".

If I were going to regard the two things as one problem, I would set off the more general description: "Globally, blindness (and visual impairment geenrally) is a major health problem". If I wanted the reader to focus on visual impairment in general and blindness as only one aspect of it, I might give visual impairment first position in the sentence: "Globally, visual impairment, including blindness, is a major health problem". Since doing things like this makes the conjunctive phrase less smooth, I might move the 'globally' to the other side: "Visual impairment, especially blindness, is a major health problem globally."

Hope that helps.

As a minor point: It is considered poor form to put "please help me" in a StackExchange post. We're all here to ask for help, there is no need to state it again.

Comment: noted and Thank you very much

Comment: In the StackExchange world, upvotes are the way we build reputation and thank each other. You can click on the up-pointing arrow at the upper-left of any answer (not just those to your own question(s)) to upvote, and the other one for answers that you think are misleading or wrong. Welcome to the community!